# Exception in BufferedImage.getData().getPixels()

Tags: java, exception, bufferedimage

I was looking to convert a buffered image to its corresponding pixel value array. I found a code for that:

```
public static double[] createArrFromIm(BufferedImage im){
      int imWidth = im.getWidth();
      int imHeight = im.getHeight();
      double[] imArr = new double[imWidth* imHeight];
      im.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, imArr);
      return imArr;
}
```

The original author who wrote this code block also gave some sample images which work perfect for this block. However, when I try to run this block against my images (the images are always 125*150) the block throws an array index out of bound exception at line:

```
      im.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, imArr);
```

This incident seems very arcane to me. Any help or suggestion will be very much appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Some tips that might help you get an answer: When you want help with an Exception, always add the full stack trace to the question! Also, if specific images are needed to reproduce the exception, you should include the code to create or read it, along with a sample file. Finally, you  refer to an "author who wrote this code block", it's probably a good idea to link to where you found the code for context. Happy coding! :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it using the raster:

```
public static double[] createArrFromIm(BufferedImage im){
    int imWidth = im.getWidth();
    int imHeight = im.getHeight();
    double[] imArr = new double[imWidth* imHeight];
    for (int y=0, nb=0 ; y < imHeight ; y++)
        for (int x=0 ; x < imWidth ; x++, nb++)
            imArr[nb] = im.getRaster().getSampleDouble(x, y, 0) ;
    return imArr;
}
```

As pointed by @haraldK, getData() also works, but it returns a copy of the raster, so it's slower.

There is a faster way using the DataBuffer, but then you have to manage the BufferedImage encoding because you have a direct access to the pixel values.

And here is the answer why what you did, didn't work. `im.getData().getPixels()` returns an array, it does not fill the array you give as parameter. The array that you give as parameter just determines the return type. So if you want to use getData (it's not the best option), you have to do:

```
double[] imArr = im.getData().getPixels(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, (double[])null) ;
```

Comment: `im.getData()` already gets the `Raster` (well, a copy of it, anyway), your method is just faster.  Why would your version work, and the OP's not? Not saying it doesn't, but an explanation would be useful.

Comment: Yes, the getData() returns a copy, so I never use it. What is "OP's", I would be glad to answer your question.

Comment: OP = Original Poster. [source](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op). The guy who wrote the question. 

Comment: Thanks :-) I took a look to the JavaDod and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @FiReTiTi says, you should use the `getRaster()` method instead of the `getData()` method, unless you *really* want a copy of the image data.

However, that is not the cause of the exception. The problem is that your `double` array only allocates space for a single band (similarly, FiReTiTi's version works, because he explicitly leaves the last parameter 0, only requesting the first band). This is fine for single band (gray scale) images, but I assume you use RGB, CMYK or other color model with multiple bands.

The fix is to multiply the allocated space with the number of bands, as below:

```
public static double[] createArrFromIm(BufferedImage im) {
    int imWidth = im.getWidth();
    int imHeight = im.getHeight();
    int imBands = im.getRaster().getNumBands(); // typically 3 or 4, depending on RGB or ARGB

    double[] imArr = new double[imWidth * imHeight * imBands];
    im.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, imWidth, imHeight, imArr);

    return imArr;
}
```